# subscrpt/superscript in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

How to subscript or superscript in Google Sheets? The Doc's shortcut (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) is not working there.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Google Sheets doesn't offer this formatting option; it's limited to bold/italic/underline/strikethrough.

Your best bet is to use Unicode superscript/subscript characters, but not all of them are available. [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909597/4751173) lists a couple of them, though whether they render correctly may depend on your OS and browser:

> Consolidated for cut-and-pasting purposes, the Unicode standard
>   defines complete sub- and super-scripts for numbers and common
>   mathematical symbols ( ⁰ ¹ ² ³ ⁴ ⁵ ⁶ ⁷ ⁸ ⁹ ⁺ ⁻ ⁼ ⁽ ⁾ ₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈
>   ₉ ₊ ₋ ₌ ₍ ₎ ), a full superscript Latin lowercase alphabet except q (
>   ᵃ ᵇ ᶜ ᵈ ᵉ ᶠ ᵍ ʰ ⁱ ʲ ᵏ ˡ ᵐ ⁿ ᵒ ᵖ ʳ ˢ ᵗ ᵘ ᵛ ʷ ˣ ʸ ᶻ ), a limited
>   uppercase Latin alphabet ( ᴬ ᴮ ᴰ ᴱ ᴳ ᴴ ᴵ ᴶ ᴷ ᴸ ᴹ ᴺ ᴼ ᴾ ᴿ ᵀ ᵁ ⱽ ᵂ ), a
>   few subscripted lowercase letters ( ₐ ₑ ₕ ᵢ ⱼ ₖ ₗ ₘ ₙ ₒ ₚ ᵣ ₛ ₜ ᵤ ᵥ ₓ
>   ), and some Greek letters ( ᵅ ᵝ ᵞ ᵟ ᵋ ᶿ ᶥ ᶲ ᵠ ᵡ ᵦ ᵧ ᵨ ᵩ ᵪ ). Note that
>   since these glyphs come from different ranges, they may not be of the
>   same size and position, depending on the typeface.

Answer (score 0):

## <sup>SUPERSCRIPT</sup> characters:

- you can either use this generator: **https://lingojam.com/SuperscriptGenerator**
- or one of these **`CHAR`** codes:

  - **<kbd>`A`</kbd> `=CHAR(7491)`**
  - **<kbd>`B`</kbd> `=CHAR(7495)`**
  - **<kbd>`C`</kbd> `=CHAR(7580)`**
  - **<kbd>`D`</kbd> `=CHAR(7496)`**
  - **<kbd>`E`</kbd> `=CHAR(7497)`**
  - **<kbd>`F`</kbd> `=CHAR(7584)`**
  - **<kbd>`G`</kbd> `=CHAR(7501)`**
  - **<kbd>`H`</kbd> `=CHAR(688)`**
  - **<kbd>`I`</kbd> `=CHAR(7588)`**
  - **<kbd>`J`</kbd> `=CHAR(690)`**
  - **<kbd>`K`</kbd> `=CHAR(7503)`**
  - **<kbd>`L`</kbd> `=CHAR(737)`**
  - **<kbd>`M`</kbd> `=CHAR(7504)`**
  - **<kbd>`N`</kbd> `=CHAR(8319)`**
  - **<kbd>`O`</kbd> `=CHAR(7506)`**
  - **<kbd>`P`</kbd> `=CHAR(7510)`**
  - **<kbd>`R`</kbd> `=CHAR(691)`**
  - **<kbd>`S`</kbd> `=CHAR(738)`**
  - **<kbd>`T`</kbd> `=CHAR(7511)`**
  - **<kbd>`U`</kbd> `=CHAR(7512)`**
  - **<kbd>`V`</kbd> `=CHAR(7515)`**
  - **<kbd>`W`</kbd> `=CHAR(695)`**
  - **<kbd>`X`</kbd> `=CHAR(739)`**
  - **<kbd>`Y`</kbd> `=CHAR(696)`**
  - **<kbd>`Z`</kbd> `=CHAR(7611)`**
  - **<kbd>`0`</kbd> `=CHAR(8304)`**
  - **<kbd>`1`</kbd> `=CHAR(185)`**
  - **<kbd>`2`</kbd> `=CHAR(178)`**
  - **<kbd>`3`</kbd> `=CHAR(179)`**
  - **<kbd>`4`</kbd> `=CHAR(8308)`**
  - **<kbd>`5`</kbd> `=CHAR(8309)`**
  - **<kbd>`6`</kbd> `=CHAR(8310)`**
  - **<kbd>`7`</kbd> `=CHAR(8311)`**
  - **<kbd>`8`</kbd> `=CHAR(8312)`**
  - **<kbd>`9`</kbd> `=CHAR(8313)`**
  - **<kbd>`+`</kbd> `=CHAR(8314)`**
  - **<kbd>`-`</kbd> `=CHAR(8315)`**
  - **<kbd>`=`</kbd> `=CHAR(8316)`**
  - **<kbd>`(`</kbd> `=CHAR(8317)`**
  - **<kbd>`)`</kbd> `=CHAR(8318)`**

---

## <sub>SUBSCRIPT</sub> characters:

- you can either use this generator: **https://lingojam.com/SubscriptGenerator**
- or one of these **`CHAR`** codes:

  - **<kbd>`A`</kbd> `=CHAR(8336)`**
  - **<kbd>`E`</kbd> `=CHAR(8337)`**
  - **<kbd>`I`</kbd> `=CHAR(7522)`**
  - **<kbd>`O`</kbd> `=CHAR(8338)`**
  - **<kbd>`R`</kbd> `=CHAR(7523)`**
  - **<kbd>`U`</kbd> `=CHAR(7524)`**
  - **<kbd>`V`</kbd> `=CHAR(7525)`**
  - **<kbd>`W`</kbd> `=CHAR(7525)&CHAR(7525)`**
  - **<kbd>`X`</kbd> `=CHAR(8339)`**
  - **<kbd>`Y`</kbd> `=CHAR(7527)`**
  - **<kbd>`0`</kbd> `=CHAR(8320)`**
  - **<kbd>`1`</kbd> `=CHAR(8321)`**
  - **<kbd>`2`</kbd> `=CHAR(8322)`**
  - **<kbd>`3`</kbd> `=CHAR(8323)`**
  - **<kbd>`4`</kbd> `=CHAR(8324)`**
  - **<kbd>`5`</kbd> `=CHAR(8325)`**
  - **<kbd>`6`</kbd> `=CHAR(8326)`**
  - **<kbd>`7`</kbd> `=CHAR(8327)`**
  - **<kbd>`8`</kbd> `=CHAR(8328)`**
  - **<kbd>`9`</kbd> `=CHAR(8329)`**
  - **<kbd>`+`</kbd> `=CHAR(8330)`**
  - **<kbd>`-`</kbd> `=CHAR(8331)`**
  - **<kbd>`=`</kbd> `=CHAR(8332)`**
  - **<kbd>`(`</kbd> `=CHAR(8333)`**
  - **<kbd>`)`</kbd> `=CHAR(8334)`**

---

## fraction characters:

- **<kbd>`1/4`</kbd> `=CHAR(188)`**
- **<kbd>`1/2`</kbd> `=CHAR(189)`**
- **<kbd>`3/4`</kbd> `=CHAR(190)`**
- **<kbd>`1/3`</kbd> `=CHAR(8531)`**
- **<kbd>`2/3`</kbd> `=CHAR(8532)`**
- **<kbd>`1/5`</kbd> `=CHAR(8533)`**
- **<kbd>`2/5`</kbd> `=CHAR(8534)`**
- **<kbd>`3/5`</kbd> `=CHAR(8535)`**
- **<kbd>`4/5`</kbd> `=CHAR(8536)`**
- **<kbd>`1/6`</kbd> `=CHAR(8537)`**
- **<kbd>`5/6`</kbd> `=CHAR(8538)`**
- **<kbd>`1/8`</kbd> `=CHAR(8539)`**
- **<kbd>`3/8`</kbd> `=CHAR(8540)`**
- **<kbd>`5/8`</kbd> `=CHAR(8541)`**
- **<kbd>`7/8`</kbd> `=CHAR(8542)`**

---

### [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OUHMXnpJIyu-e7p-smB8qaSETZCgmi8wJa_x8PZEKkY/edit#gid=0) containing first 174000 characters

- row number = **`CHAR`** code
- tofu  character = given font does not support such character

Comment: To use these 'Char' wouldn't i have to keep referring the character code? This might become a tough task.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "referring"... if you mean this: `="H"&CHAR(8322)&"O"` then yeah > H₂O

Comment: Yeah. I mean the numbers that are inside the brackets. I am new to these reference numbers. So I might need to mug up them to use quickly.